PrimeNG floatLabel is not working properly
I am using Angular 17 with PrimeNG and I have an issue where p-floatLabel doesn't work as intended. There's no error anywhere but the label doesn't float.
I don't know what I'm supposed to do.
Here's my html:
<div>
    <p-floatLabel>
        <input pInputText id="username"/>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
    </p-floatLabel>
</div>

Also, here's the beginning of my component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import { FloatLabelModule } from 'primeng/floatlabel';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ButtonModule, InputTextModule, FloatLabelModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.sass'
})

The label and the input are shown, but the label isn't doing what it is supposed to do according to PrimeNG
Thank you

please replicate the issue on this stackblitz and share back!

I can't seem to replicate the issue. But I am also using TailWindCSS. Can it be the cause of my issue?

possibly, try integrating the tailwind CSS on stackblitz

It did nothing... On Stackblitz, it works just fine... I don't know what I've done, but it doesn,'t seem to work on my project

in my Stackblitz approach it works as expected. For a correct label function, there must be nothing in the input field.
For a more specific solution, you would need to share more of your source code. Since I can't read the problem from your current one.
Edit: Do you import the browseranimations module in angular and the animations module from primeng?
